# Grafana with Elasticsearch - Does not show data when setting Group By Average

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grafana, fluentd

Using Grafana 7.2 and Elasticsearch 7.5.1.

Everyting is up and running in Openshift. Elasticsearch datasource is correctly configured and a very simple Dashboard created.

From a Springboot service also running in Openshift I am sending logs to Elasticsearch using Fluentd.

The documents stored in Elasticsearch are like this (taken from Grafana "Logs" result panel):

[image]

Edited: following @karan shah suggestion, I add the original log that I am sending to Elastichsearch through Fluentd:

```
{
   "onpay":{
      "traceId":"9999",
      "inout":"OUT",
      "startTime":"2020-10-01T10:13:43.806+0200",
      "finishTime":"2020-10-01T10:13:43.827+0200",
      "executionTime":21.0,
      "entrySize":124.0,
      "exitSize":124.0,
      "differenceSize":0.0,
      "user":"pgallello",
      "methodPath":"http://localhost:8083/api/serviceEntryPoint",
      "errorMessage":null,
      "className":"com.myorganization.mypackage.MyController",
      "methodName":"serviceTemplateEntryPoint"
   }
}
```

It is a Elasticsearch document with a field "message", which is the one I want to base my dashboard in.
Note two things at this point:

- The field remarked in red: **executionTime**.
- The field _source just have an [object Object] value.

Problem 1:

What I need to do (and I am not getting) is the tricky part: I need to get an histogram showing the average of the value of executionTime field per interval.

Following official documentation, particularly [this official video from Grafana](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hEztaMtobXw&t=127s), I should be able to change de Group By field to Average and to select @value from the field selector. Unfortunately, that @value value does not appear there (May the `_source = [object Object]` field have something to do?)

[image]

Problem 2:

The other doubt is whether the Query field is valid in that format or what is the way to access to the **executionTime** field, which is inside the **message** field inside the Elasticsearch document. In a sort of hierarchy `message -> onpay -> executionTime`.

Fluentd config file:

```
  <source>
    @type forward
    port 24224
    bind "0.0.0.0"
  </source>
  <filter onpayapp.**>
    @type parser
    key_name "onpayapp"
    reserve_data true
    <parse>
      @type "json"
    </parse>
  </filter>
  <match onpay.**>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type "elasticsearch"
      host "elasticdb"
      port 9200
      logstash_format true
      logstash_prefix "applogs"
      logstash_dateformat "%Y%m%d"
      include_tag_key true
      type_name "app_log"
      tag_key "@log_name"
      flush_interval 1s
      <parse>
        @type json
      </parse>
      <buffer>
        flush_interval 1s
      </buffer>
    </store>
    <store>
      @type "stdout"
    </store>
  </match>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently what you have there is the entire json as a string in the message field. So Elastic would not be able to apply any mathematical operations on that. What you need to do is using fluentd parse the log line as json so in the Elastic document every field (like logger and level) within that json is part of the elastic document.
Once you have that Elastic mostly automatically interpret that executionTime is number and make it available for aggregations. After that you will see that field in your Grafana dropdown.

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html) you can understand more on _source field.

Add your original log line as well to the question, I think it might help understand what you want to ingest so a suggestion can be made on the possible fluentd configuration.

***Updated Answer based on additional information provided***

For simplicity I used docker setup to run and parse the log pattern provided in the question.

**Fluentd Configuration**

I have used HTTP input so it allows me to curl but you can switch back to forwarder.
I have removed filter as I am assuming your source is already JSON so you do not need to parse it as JSON.
You can add the matching pattern back if you have multiple types of data processed through the pipeline.

```
 <source>
    @type http
    port 9880
    bind 0.0.0.0
  </source>
  <match *>
    @type copy
    <store>
      @type "elasticsearch"
      host "es01"
      port 9200
      logstash_format true
      logstash_prefix "applogs"
      logstash_dateformat "%Y%m%d"
      include_tag_key true
      type_name "app_log"
      tag_key "@log_name"
      flush_interval 1s
      <parse>
        @type json
      </parse>
      <buffer>
        flush_interval 1s
      </buffer>
    </store>
    <store>
      @type "stdout"
    </store>
  </match>
```

***Fluent Docker Image***

```
# fluentd/Dockerfile
FROM fluent/fluentd:v1.11-debian-1

USER root

RUN touch ~/.gemrc
RUN echo ':ssl_verify_mode: 0' >> ~/.gemrc

RUN buildDeps="sudo make gcc g++ libc-dev" \
 && apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $buildDeps \
 && sudo gem install fluent-plugin-elasticsearch \
 && sudo gem sources --clear-all \
 && SUDO_FORCE_REMOVE=yes \
    apt-get purge -y --auto-remove \
                  -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false \
                  $buildDeps \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && rm -rf /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/lib/ruby/gems/*/cache/*.gem


USER fluent
```

**Docker Compose**
You can choose to run just one node of elasticsearch. I already had this setup running.

```
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
    healthcheck:
      interval: 20s
      retries: 10
      test: curl -s http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health | grep -vq '"status":"red"'

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
    healthcheck:
      interval: 20s
      retries: 10
      test: curl -s http://localhost:9201/_cluster/health | grep -vq '"status":"red"'

  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.8.0
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9202:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
    healthcheck:
      interval: 20s
      retries: 10
      test: curl -s http://localhost:9202/_cluster/health | grep -vq '"status":"red"'

  kib01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.8.0
    container_name: kib01
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://es01:9200
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
    healthcheck:
      interval: 10s
      retries: 20
      test: curl --write-out 'HTTP %{http_code}' --fail --silent --output /dev/null http://localhost:5601/api/status
  
  fluentd:
    build: ./fluentd
    volumes:
      - "./fluentd/conf/:/fluentd/etc/:ro"
    networks:
      - elastic
    ports:
      - "9880:9880"

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

**Curl for Test**

```
curl -X POST -d 'json={    "onpay": {        "traceId": "9999",        "inout": "OUT",        "startTime": "2020-10-01T10:13:43.806+0200",        "finishTime": "2020-10-01T10:13:43.827+0200",        "executionTime": 21.0,        "entrySize": 124.0,        "exitSize": 124.0,        "differenceSize": 0.0,        "user": "pgallello",        "methodPath": "http://localhost:8083/api/serviceEntryPoint",        "errorMessage": null,        "className": "com.myorganization.mypackage.MyController",        "methodName": "serviceTemplateEntryPoint"    }}' http://localhost:9880/
```

**Result in Elastic Search**
[image: ElasticSearch]

Once you get all your json keys ingested like this, Elastic will auto-map most fields and allow search, aggregation etc based on the field type. You can change the field type & formatting from kibana index management if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @karan. Just edited the question with the original log line. Just to make sure, one question: your first two paragraphs do answer two different things, right? The first points to the solution and the second just answers what I say about the _source field. But the solution to the main story would be contained just in your main explanation (first paragraph), right? Now figuring out what to configure in Fluentd to get the fields in my message to be among the main Elasticsearch document fields

Comment: Yes @EIPiter  the first point answers your main question the second one is just from an understanding perspective. Looking at your source log I think its just about getting your ingestion via fluentd correct. Based on how you do that you would either get `onpay.executionTime` or `executionTime` in your elastic document after which it would be accessible from Grafana.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Believe me that I am reading a lot of official documentation about what to tell Fluentd to get executionTime in my Elastic document. But still not getting it :(. I'll keep trying... but if you have a clue it would be very appreciated :)

Comment: Can you share your fluentd config please. I have already got an Elastic setup in docker, will spin up a fluentd container and see if I can help you nail down the exact config.

Comment: Hi, I have simplified the config file a little removing some fields that were not necessary. Anyway, the result is still the same :(. Any clue? Thanks!!

Comment: @EIPiter, I was able to ingest the log sample you provided. Have updated the answer.

Comment: Karan Shah, your answer is just brilliant. In fact, just as you did, when I go throug curl POST I have gotten to recieve and index structured fields in my Elasticsearch document. But we are not done yet: if I change to ´source type forward´, it again changes its behavior and stores the message field as a whole json string. So there is something that happens between logback and fluentd that formats the message in some other way. Any clue? Is there anyway to "debug" the fluentd behavior? I.e., something that let me see what exactly fluentd recieves?. Thanks for all, mate!! :)

Comment: At this point, it is fair to consider this question as already answered ;). I'll post a new one in which I'll query about my other problem: why it is working when we perform a curl post with json and not when logging from logback with the Fluent appender. A this point it's all a matter of that. Thank you!

Comment: Just posted this new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205516/logback-fluentd-json-message-is-not-deserialized-when-sent-to-elasticsearch

Comment: Hi Karan :) Would you take a look to this new problem I got? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64669749/fluentd-is-not-filtering-as-intended-before-writing-to-elasticsearch